# When the loop comes to a continue statement at the end it doesn't restart from the top

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

Ok, so I have created the following program. It is not yet complete but when the code comes to the end (y or n part) and the user decides to try again they don't get the option to enter a new bet it just uses the one entered from the first time.

(Please comment if you need help about understanding the code or thinking it might be hard for other people to understand)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab15 {
    static Scanner kin = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double money = 1000;
        System.out.println("Welcom To Craps You Start With 1000$!!!");
        int play = 1; //variable to cancel whole loop
        char yesNo; //if user wants to continue playing or not

        while(money > 0 && play == 1) {
            System.out.print("Please Enter The Amount You Want To Bet: ");
            double bet = kin.nextDouble();
            while((bet <= money || bet > 0)) {
                do { //loop to test if the bet is legit
                    if(money < bet || bet < 0) {
                        System.out.print("Sorry Invalid Bet; Please Enter A Legitimant Bet: ");
                        bet = kin.nextDouble();
                    }
                } while(bet > money || bet < 0);

                money -= bet;
                System.out.println("You Have Bet $" + bet + " And Have " + money + " Left");

                int die1 = (1 + (int) (6 * Math.random()));
                int die2 = (1 + (int) (3 * Math.random()));
                int sum = die1 + die2;
                System.out.println("You Rolled " + die1 + " and " + die2 + " totaling " + sum);              

                System.out.print("Do You Want To Play Again(y) Or Not(n)");
                yesNo = kin.next().charAt(0);

                int loopBreak = 0; //to break do while loop bellow

                do {
                    if(yesNo == 'y') { //take above yes no to restart loop or not
                        System.out.println("Restarting...");
                        loopBreak += 1;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if(yesNo == 'n') {
                        System.out.println("Thank You For Playing");
                        play -= 1; //to cancel whole program
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Please Enter 'y' Or 'n'");
                    }
                } while(loopBreak == 0);

                if(play == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what your code doing, your continue will continue from the do beginning, Try to make it break in able to break and start the first while

Answer (score 0):

Its all about nested while loop don't stop when it needed. Its like this

```
 while(money > 0 && play == 1) {
     System.out.print("Please Enter The Amount You Want To Bet: ");
     double bet = kin.nextDouble();
     while((bet <= money || bet > 0)) {

         ...

         do {
             if(yesNo == 'y') { //take above yes no to restart loop or not
                 System.out.println("Restarting...");
                 loopBreak += 1;
                 continue;
             }
             else if(yesNo == 'n') {
                 System.out.println("Thank You For Playing");
                 play -= 1; //to cancel whole program
                 break;
             }
             else {
                 System.out.println("Please Enter 'y' Or 'n'");
             }
         } while(loopBreak == 0);

         if(play == 0) {
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

After you get answer `'y'` you don't break the nested while and program never get the

```
 while(money > 0 && play == 1) {
 --> System.out.print("Please Enter The Amount You Want To Bet: ");
 --> double bet = kin.nextDouble();
     //because below while loop continues to loop
     while((bet <= money || bet > 0)) {

     ...

    }
}
```

part. Anyways corrected code is here(i tried every possibility and it worked)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab15 {
    static Scanner kin = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double money = 1000;
        System.out.println("Welcom To Craps You Start With 1000$!!!");
        int play = 1; //variable to cancel whole loop
        char yesNo; //if user wants to continue playing or not

        while(money > 0 && play == 1) {
            System.out.print("Please Enter The Amount You Want To Bet: ");
            double bet = kin.nextDouble();
            while((bet <= money || bet > 0)) {
                do { //loop to test if the bet is legit
                    if(money < bet || bet < 0) {
                        System.out.print("Sorry Invalid Bet; Please Enter A Legitimant Bet: ");
                        bet = kin.nextDouble();
                    }
                } while(bet > money || bet < 0);

                money -= bet;
                System.out.println("You Have Bet $" + bet + " And Have " + money + " Left");

                int die1 = (1 + (int) (6 * Math.random()));
                int die2 = (1 + (int) (3 * Math.random()));
                int sum = die1 + die2;
                System.out.println("You Rolled " + die1 + " and " + die2 + " totaling " + sum);              

                System.out.print("Do You Want To Play Again(y) Or Not(n): ");
                yesNo = kin.next().charAt(0);

                int loopBreak = 0; //to break do while loop bellow

                do {
                    if(yesNo == 'y') { //take above yes no to restart loop or not
                        System.out.println("Restarting...");
                        loopBreak++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if(yesNo == 'n') {
                        System.out.println("Thank You For Playing");
                        play--; //to cancel whole program
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Please Enter 'y' Or 'n': ");
                    }
                } while(loopBreak == 0);

                if(play == 0 || loopBreak == 1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use labeled breaks/continues https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

However it should be used sparingly (or not at all). You probably can simplify it in some other way.

```
package test.test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab15 {
    static Scanner kin = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double money = 1000;
        System.out.println("Welcom To Craps You Start With 1000$!!!");
        int play = 1; // variable to cancel whole loop
        char yesNo; // if user wants to continue playing or not

        //Labeled <-----------------
        start: while (money > 0 && play == 1) {
            System.out.print("Please Enter The Amount You Want To Bet: ");
            double bet = kin.nextDouble();
            while ((bet <= money || bet > 0)) {
                do { // loop to test if the bet is legit
                    if (money < bet || bet < 0) {
                        System.out.print("Sorry Invalid Bet; Please Enter A Legitimant Bet: ");
                        bet = kin.nextDouble();
                    }
                } while (bet > money || bet < 0);

                money -= bet;
                System.out.println("You Have Bet $" + bet + " And Have " + money + " Left");

                int die1 = (1 + (int) (6 * Math.random()));
                int die2 = (1 + (int) (3 * Math.random()));
                int sum = die1 + die2;
                System.out.println("You Rolled " + die1 + " and " + die2 + " totaling " + sum);

                System.out.print("Do You Want To Play Again(y) Or Not(n)");
                yesNo = kin.next().charAt(0);

                int loopBreak = 0; // to break do while loop bellow

                do {
                    if (yesNo == 'y') { // take above yes no to restart loop or not
                        System.out.println("Restarting...");
                        loopBreak += 1;
                        //Labeled continue <-----------------
                        continue start; 
                    } else if (yesNo == 'n') {
                        System.out.println("Thank You For Playing");
                        play -= 1; // to cancel whole program
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Please Enter 'y' Or 'n'");
                    }
                } while (loopBreak == 0);

                if (play == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```